# WrappingStyle/Align Image not working in a header section

Tags: php, phpword

I'm currently working with PhpWord. I added a `header` section, and inside it, added two images. Images need to be aligned, one left and the other right, but in the same line. And I have this code but only prints the images one below the other, only way I can change them is insde the .docx file.

```
$header = $section->addHeader();
$header->addImage('http://localhost/doWords/logoRenatea.jpg',
    array(
        'width' => '291',
        'height' => '81',
        'align' => 'left',
        'marginTop' => -1,
        'marginLeft' => -1,
        'wrappingStyle' => 'behind'
        ));
$header->addImage('http://localhost/doWords/logoMTESS.jpg',
    array(
        'width' => '110',
        'height' => '44',
        'align' => 'right',
        'marginTop' => -1,
        'marginLeft' => -1,
        'wrappingStyle' => 'infront'
        ));
```

Already tried without wrappingStyle, without margins, and not worked. Any ideas?

Output:

[image]

Desired: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that `align` does not accept `left` or `right` values. It prefers `start` and `end` respectively. But that's not all. I also needed to add position absolute. So here is the code:

```
$header->addImage('http://localhost/doWords/logoRenatea.jpg',
    array(
        'width' => '291',
        'height' => '81',
        'align' => 'start',
        'positioning' => 'absolute'
        ));
$image1 = $header->addImage('http://localhost/doWords/logoMTESS.jpg',
    array(
        'width' => '110',
        'height' => '44',
        'align' => 'end'
        ));
```

The only thing that I could not manage to get to work are margins, but I aligned the images, that was the main issue.

Answer (score 3):

table is an easy way to get your images to the same line

```
...
$table = $header->addTable(array('width' => '5000', 'unit' => 'pct'));
$table->addRow();
$table->addCell(2000)->addImage(...); // image1 with needed styles
$table->addCell(2000)->addTextRun(array('align' => 'right'))->addImage(...); // image2 with needed styles
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it... but I've already solve it, will post answer with my solution