# PHPWord - Position TextBox in the top right inside a footer

Tags: phpword

I'm using PHPWord to create a Word document and I've been trying to move a TextBox element to the top right inside a footer but I can't make it work. This is the closest thing I could get

```
$footer = $section->addFooter();
$textbox = $footer->addTextBox(['width' => 200, 'height' => 60, 'stroke' => 0, 'innerMargin' => 0, 'align' => 'left', 'borderSize' => 0]);
$textbox->addText("ADDRESS", [], ['align' => 'center']);

$textbox = $footer->addTextBox(['width' => 200, 'height' => 60, 'stroke' => 0, 'innerMargin' => 0,  'align' => 'right', 'borderSize' => 0]);
$textbox->addText("NUMBERS", [], ['align' => 'center']);
```

[image]

I've also used posHorizontal, posHorizontalRel, and so on but the textboxes get stacked. I tried to use absolute position for each TextBox but they go to the top left of the page.

What are the correct properties to pass to `->addTextBox([...])` to move a textbox to the top right of the footer?

Comment: You could try with the two solutions available here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33502891/wrappingstyle-align-image-not-working-in-a-header-section (one with working style definitions for images in same problem situation - and a generic solution that uses table)

Comment: The accepted solution on that question is not valid for text boxes. I think the only solution I have now is just using a table. I'll try it!